# How to bring data in a row

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table showing courses details with Thymeleaf to call data and I have "Apply" button to apply the course. I want to bring the value in the row from course.html to applycourse.html when clicking the  "Apply" button.

course.html

```
<table id="coursetable" class="coursetable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Course Code</th>
            <th>Course No</th>
            <th>Course Name</th>
            <th>Course Date (Time)</th>
            <th>Apply</th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr  th:each="class : ${inclass}" th:data-row="${class}">
            
            <td th:text="${class.classStatus}"></td>
            <td th:text="${class.courseId.courseCode}" 
            th:style="${class.courseId.courseCode}"></td>
            <td th:text="${class.classNo}"></td>
            <td th:text="${class.courseId.courseTitleEng}"></td>
            <td th:text="${class.classDate}"></td>
            <td><a  href="../CourseRegistration-NotesForOnlineApplication/individual/individualapplication" class="spinner-trigger-button">Apply</a></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Thymeleaf's [Standard URL Syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) to put variables into URLs.  For example:

```
<td>
    <a th:href="@{../CourseRegistration-NotesForOnlineApplication/individual/individualapplication(classNo=${class.classNo})}" class="spinner-trigger-button">Apply</a>
</td>
```

would produce a URL something like:

```
<a th:href="../CourseRegistration-NotesForOnlineApplication/individual/individualapplication?classNo=500" class="spinner-trigger-button">Apply</a>
```

Comment: Hello, by this method, can I use the data of that row in applycourse.html like to make another table.

Comment: You pass the id of the course, then use the id of the course to load the data for the new page you are on.